# Demuxer: Could not open

Tags: browser, media

When I play a video file into [vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/) on LFS-based distro, I am getting an error saying

**ERROR:render_media_log.cc(27) MediaEvent: PIPELINE_ERROR demuxer: could not open**

I am unable to play any video file into this browser.

I tried to install same application onto Ubuntu, and it was performing well without any complaints.

If I play same file into chrome/firefox then it plays very well.